# How to fix these error while loading ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

**Edit:**
These errors are hidden by setting the loglevel to be 3 following this answer: https://www.linux.org/threads/acpi-error-after-installing-ubuntu-22-04.40993/#post-164104

---

I have the following error showing up before loading the Ubuntu (which opens up without problems).

[image]

I also have a dual boot, and the grub color is black, I am not sure why it is not the default of purple. It is not a console as I checked the grub text and the console setting is commented.

Comment: Does the computer boot after these errors or does it get stuck at this point? How old is the computer? Newer versions of Ubuntu have black background for Grub. Newer kernels check for many security features in the hardware and BIOS, that didn't exist some years ago. These can result in error messages that do not stop the computer from booting.

Comment: As stated here too many times already, those messages can be ignored if the system boots correctly. Update UEFI ("BIOS") / wait for newer kernel... One or both of the aforementioned conditions *may* eventually correct it. The Grub menu background has been like this for years.